# How to separate an associative array with a comma separated value?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array-like

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2,2-0-tc
    [1] => 2-0
    [2] => 2-0-tc
    [3] => 3,3-0-sc-v6
    [4] => 3-0-sc-v6
    [5] => 3-0sc-v6
    [6] => 5-0-sc-v8
)
```

and I want to extract the comma separated value from array and then create new array like

```
Array
(
    [2] => 2,2-0-tc
    [2-0-tc] => 2,2-0-tc
    [2-0] => 2-0
    [3] => 3,3-0-sc-v6
    [3-0-sc-v6] => 3,3-0-sc-v6
    [3-0sc-v6] => 3-0sc-v6
    [5-0-sc-v8] => 5-0-sc-v8
)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: For general question I can give general answer: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: @Parmar If you want stop the downvotes on your question, please edit your question to fix the `fist` typo and add your best (unsuccessful) coding attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explode and iterate each comma-delimited value and prevent overwriting with an isset condition.

Code: demo: https://3v4l.org/9ArV7

```
$array = [
    "2,2-0-tc",
    "2-0",
    "2-0-tc",
    "3,3-0-sc-v6",
    "3-0-sc-v6",
    "3-0sc-v6",
    "5-0-sc-v8"
];

foreach ($array as $item) {
    $values = explode(",", $item);
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        if (!isset($result[$value])) {
             $result[$value] = $item;
        }
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  2 => '2,2-0-tc',
  '2-0-tc' => '2,2-0-tc',
  '2-0' => '2-0',
  3 => '3,3-0-sc-v6',
  '3-0-sc-v6' => '3,3-0-sc-v6',
  '3-0sc-v6' => '3-0sc-v6',
  '5-0-sc-v8' => '5-0-sc-v8',
)
```

Answer (score -1):

explode the comma separated values and assign it to new array.

```
$arr = array
(
    0 => '2,2-0-tc',
    1 => '2-0',
    2 => '2-0-tc',
    3 => '3,3-0-sc-v6',
    4 => '3-0-sc-v6',
    5 => '3-0sc-v6',
    6 => '5-0-sc-v8'
);

$newArr = [];
foreach($arr as $key=>$val){ 
    $temp = explode (',', $val);
    foreach($temp as $new){
        $newArr[$new] = $val;
    }
}
print_r($newArr);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/3cVPP)